# PHP - get same line inside row

Tags: php, string, substr

Text 1:

```
<div class="b3id-instrument-details-label">Text 1</div>
```

Text 2:

```
<div class="b3id-instrument-details-label">Text 2</div>
```

RESULT:

```
Text1
Text2
```

I have two identical div headers as I showed in the example but the difference is the strings inside them are different what i want is to get the content of these two lines with php

Comment: You didn't ask a question here. Do you have PHP code as well you are having issues with? Are you getting an error? Are you trying to parse this HTML?

Comment: all i want is to get rows inside these two div

Comment: See https://3v4l.org/d2ip2

Answer (score 0):

The best way to do this - regular expressions:

```
<?php

preg_match(
    '@<div class="b3id-instrument-details-label">(.+)</div>@', // pattern
    '<div class="b3id-instrument-details-label">BLA BLA BLA</div>', // data
    $m // result
);

echo $m[1];
```

[php code online](https://phpize.online/s/h)

Comment: For HTML parsing the best way is regex??

Comment: Depends. When I need to parse HTML document will use `DOMDocument` class but  when I need parse single string will use `REGEXP`

Comment: dude i need to get both at the same time

Comment: @SüleymanHamdi, Use preg_match_all https://phpize.online/s/Y